# Python Pandas Compare 2 dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

i'm working on python with Pandas and i have 2 dataFrame

```
1 'A'
2 'B'
    
1 'A'
2 'B'
3 'C'
4 'D'
```

and i want to return the difference:

```
1 'C'
2 'D'
```

Comment: If your thing really is just a difference, the obvious first step would be to do something like `[s for s in first_list if not in second_list]`. Is your data more complex than that?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two dataframes and drop duplicates:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

If your dataframe contains more columns you can add a certain column name as a subset:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='col_name', keep=False)
```

Comment: you can add subset option in your answer -> `pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset = 'col_name' , keep = False)`

Comment: @Nk03 Thanks, I added it as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

What i retrieve with  `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`
(N = name of column)

```
df1:
    N
0   A
1   B
2   C

df2:
    N
0   A
1   B
2   C

df3
    N
0   A
1   B
2   C
0   A
1   B
2   C
```

Value in df is phone Number without '+' in it. i can't show them.
i import them with :

df1 = pd.DataFrame(ListResponse, columns=['33000000000'])

df2 = pd.read_csv('number.csv')

ListResponse return List with number and number.csv is ListResponse that i save in csv the last time i run the script

edit:
(what i want in this case is "Empty DataFrame")

just test with new value :

```
 df3:
       N
    0  A
    1  B
    2  C
    3  D
    0  B
    1  C
    2  D
```

Edit2: i think drop_duplicate is not working because my func implement new value as index = 0  and not index = length+1 like you can see just above. but when same values in both df, it not return me empty df...